# ANT Task: SonarQube Scanner Code Coverage report using JaCoCo

Tags: ant, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan

I'm using the below property to generate JaCoCo XML report

```
<property name="sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths" value="${basedir}/sonar-task/reports/jacoco.xml" />
```

When I invoke this ANT Task from Jenkins, I'm seeing the below exception in Jenkins logs and so I don't see the Code Coverage value in SonarQube

```
15:09:49  [sonar:sonar] Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
15:09:49  [sonar:sonar] SonarQube Ant Task version: 2.6.0.1426
.
.
.
15:14:55  [sonar:sonar] Sensor JavaSquidSensor [java] (done) | time=262215ms
15:14:55  [sonar:sonar] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
15:14:55  [sonar:sonar] Coverage report 'C:\Softwares\Jenkins\workspace\MYA_DevOps_PIPELINE\.\sonar-task\reports\jacoco.xml' could not be read/imported. Error: {}
15:14:55  [sonar:sonar] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to parse JaCoCo XML report: C:\Softwares\Jenkins\workspace\MYA_DevOps_PIPELINE\.\sonar-task\reports\jacoco.xml
15:14:55  [sonar:sonar]     at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.XmlReportParser.parse(XmlReportParser.java:96)
```

I can see the HTML reports and I can see the jacoco.xml file is getting generated as well. But the content inside this file is not XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the below line while you generate an XML JaCoCo report

```
<xml destfile="${sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths}"/>
```